# Shouldn't calling Free on an object reference set to nil throw an Access Violation every time it is called?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm getting access violations from the unit `DBXCommon.pas` (in Delphi XE). When I look at the code I see things like the following (at the exclamation marks):

```
function TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection(const DBXContext: TDBXContext;
  const ConnectionProperties: TDBXProperties): TDBXConnection;
var
  ConnectionBuilder:  TDBXConnectionBuilder;
  DelegatePath:       TDBXDelegateItem;
  Connection:         TDBXConnection;
  CombinedProperties: TDBXProperties;
begin
  //...
  ConnectionBuilder := TDBXConnectionBuilder.Create;
  Connection        := nil;
  try
    //..lots of setting ConnectionBuilder properties
    ConnectionBuilder.FInputPassword := CombinedProperties[TDBXPropertyNames.Password];
    Connection := ConnectionBuilder.CreateConnection;
    Connection.Open;
    Result     := Connection;
!!  Connection := nil;
  finally
!!  Connection.Free;
    ConnectionBuilder.Free;
  end;
end;
```

But I see constructs like this (first assign Nil, then a Free) much more in `DBXCommon.pas`. Is this some construct I do not know, or is this really causing access violation **every time** this piece of code is called?

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things

Comment: @user this does not seem to be a dupe.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calling `Free` on a null reference is always safe. Go look in the implementation of `TObject.Free` to see why.

This code is an example of a *factory function*. Its job is to create a new instance of a class, but if it fails, it needs to make sure it doesn't leak a half-created instance when it throws an exception, so it calls `Free`. When it's sure it's going to succeed, it transfers ownership of the result to the caller. It still calls `Free`, but if it's already transfered ownership, then it ends up calling `Free` on a null reference, and there's no harm done. This code is what transfers ownership:

```
Result := Connection;
Connection := nil;
```

The way *I* would write a factory function would do away with the separate `Connection` variable. I'd construct the result directly in `Result`, but free it if there were an exception, like this:

```
function TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnection(const DBXContext: TDBXContext;
  const ConnectionProperties: TDBXProperties): TDBXConnection;
var
  ConnectionBuilder:  TDBXConnectionBuilder;
  DelegatePath:       TDBXDelegateItem;
  Connection:         TDBXConnection;
  CombinedProperties: TDBXProperties;
begin
  //...
  ConnectionBuilder := TDBXConnectionBuilder.Create;
  try
    //..lots of setting ConnectionBuilder properties
    ConnectionBuilder.FInputPassword := CombinedProperties[TDBXPropertyNames.Password];
    Result := ConnectionBuilder.CreateConnection;
    try
      Result.Open;
    except
      Result.Free;
      raise;
    end;
  finally
    ConnectionBuilder.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That has the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, somewhere in the back of my head I knew this. However, writing it as you show would be clearer for the untrained eye.

Comment: +1 this is the idiomatic way to write a function that returns a new object

Comment: I agree with David, except that if you do not re-raise exceptions, you should set the Result to nil. It's something we do in performance critical code where checking for a non-nil result is faster than raising and handling an exception...

Comment: @Marjan, if you do not re-raise exceptions, then you must be handling them. That's fine. Fixing the problem that caused an exception to be raised is a very good thing to do. But most code is not in a position to fix all (or even *any*) of the problems that might lead to exceptions. Any code that catches an exception but neither fixes the problem nor re-raises it is wrong.

Comment: @RobKennedy: No arguments there from me :). The code I am talking about is indeed set up to go on as best it can, try alternatives, or roll back whatever it started. It's a server pulling 80+ GigaBytes in memory and with a load time of up to a couple of hours we don't want it to fall over just because something happens not to be available...

Answer (score 7):

It is safe to call `Free` on `nil` reference as it's implementation checks for `Self <> nil` before calling `Destroy`. See Allen Bauer's explanation in [Embarcadero forum](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=421277&tstart=0#421277) why `TObject.Free` was introduced. I include only the relevant quote here:

> The sole reason for introducing the non-virtual Free method on TObject, was for use in destructors as a simple shorthand for:

```
if FField <> nil then
  FField.Destroy;
```

Comment: haven't learned the lesson by now? people should stop linking to Embarcadero webpages. they are there for only 2-3 years. then... pufffff. gone  :) :)

Answer (score 4):

`TObject.Free` is basically implemented as `if Self <> nil then Destroy`, so the code above should not raise any exception.

Comment: All the other answers are too complex and deviate too much from the point. I think this answer should be the accepted one.