# Is it possible for TStringList to automatically free the objects attached to its items?

Tags: delphi

I am adding some `TObject` descendants to a `TStringList`, for example by calling `AddObject`. I would like them to be freed when I free the list object. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148659/how-to-free-objects-in-stringlist-in-delphi-7, but that question is poorly written. That's what's keeping me from voting to close as dupe.

Comment: @iMan I removed the code from the question. There's not much point including that in the question since it pretty much answers the question. If you answer your own question it's best to keep the answer part in the answer. In any case, the implementation details as not needed, it's enough to refer to the documentation, as I have done in my edit to your answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Actually I found the answer as I was writing the question, and thought perhaps writing it here would save someone else a few minutes

Comment: Anyway, adding `OwnsObjects` to an  older stringlist is not very hard

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`OwnsObjects`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList.OwnsObjects) property of `TStringList` should be set to `True` in order for the list to free its objects when being destroyed. This can be achieved either by calling the [constructor overload that receives the `OwnsObjects` parameter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList.Create), or by explicitly setting the property after creation. It is preferable to set `OwnsObjects` as part of the object's construction.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList.OwnsObjects) describes the property like this:

> The **OwnsObjects** property specifies whether the string list owns the stored objects or not. If the **OwnsObjects** property is set to True, then the Destroy destructor will free up the memory allocated for those objects.

Comment: is there a field for TStrings?

Comment: @none, if you meant, if the `OwnsObjects` property is available in `TStrings` class, then the answer is no, since this mechanism has been implemented in `TStringList`, not in its ancestor, `TStrings` class.