# Delphi XE2 Service not stopping properly

Tags: delphi, service, delphi-xe2

I've built a few services in Delphi 7 and did not have this problem. Now that I started a new service app in XE2, it won't stop properly. I don't know if it's something I'm doing wrong or if it might be a bug in the XE2 services.

The execute procedure looks like this:

```
procedure TMySvc.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    Startup;
    try
      while not Terminated do begin
        DoSomething; //Problem persists even when nothing's here
      end;
    finally
      Cleanup;
      CoUninitialize;
    end;
  except
    on e: exception do begin
      PostLog('EXCEPTION in Execute: '+e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I never have an exception, as you can see I log any exception. `PostLog` saves to an INI file, which works fine. Now I do use ADO components, so I use `CoInitialize()` and `CoUninitialize`. It does connect to the DB and do its job properly. The problem only happens when I stop this service. Windows gives me the following message:

[image: First stop failure]

Then the service continues. I have to stop it a second time. The second time it does stop, but with the following message:

[image: Second stop failure]

The log file indicates that the service did successfully free (`OnDestroy` event was logged) but it never successfully stopped (`OnStop` was never logged).

In my above code, I have two procedures `Startup` and `Cleanup`. These simply create/destroy and initialize/uninitialize my necessary things...

```
procedure TMySvc.Startup;
begin
  FUpdateThread:= TMyUpdateThread.Create;
    FUpdateThread.OnLog:= LogUpdate;
    FUpdateThread.Resume;
end;

procedure TMySvc.Cleanup;
begin
  FUpdateThread.Terminate;
end;
```

As you can see, I have a secondary thread running. This service actually has numerous threads running like this, and the main service thread is only logging the events from each thread. Each thread has different responsibilities. The threads are reporting properly, and they are also being terminated properly.

What could be causing this stop failure? If my posted code doesn't expose anything, then I can post more code later - just have to 'convert' it because of internal naming, etc.

**EDIT**

I just started  NEW service project in Delphi XE2, and have the same issue. This is all my code below:

```
unit JDSvc;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes, JDSvcMgr;

type
  TJDService = class(TService)
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
  private
    FAfterInstall: TServiceEvent;
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
  end;

var
  JDService: TJDService;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  JDService.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TJDService.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TJDService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do begin

  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Unlikely to be a bug in the Delphi code. Can you cut this down to a minimal reproduction.

Comment: ^^ +1. It seems your thread is never terminating, hence the timeout in SCM

Comment: IMHO the TMySvc.Cleanup routine is bound to create problems. You terminate FUpdateThread but you don't know when it is really terminated. Add a WaitFor or use a synchro object to detect termination properly. Look here for more info: http://www.eonclash.com/Tutorials/Multithreading/MartinHarvey1.1/Ch5.html

Comment: Presumably somewhere you run `FUpdateThread.Free` which will call WaitFor

Comment: My thread initializes its self with `FreeOnTerminate:= True;`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Are you sure? When I look at `TThread.Free` I see the traditional `TObject.Free`. Also, adding `WaitFor` did not work, still have the problem.

Comment: @Jerry Well yes. Free is a static method! May I refer you to my answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things/8550628#8550628  The point is what is in the virtual destructor `Destroy`. And yes, `WaitFor` is called.

Comment: As for `FreeOnTerminate`, that could easily be the problem. Why are you doing that? Why would you want to do that. Set `FreeOnTerminate` to False and call `FUpdateThread.Free` from `Cleanup`. No point calling `Terminate` since that will be done for you when you call `Free`.

Comment: @JerryDodge TThread.destroy calls waitfor. One good piece of advice: never use freeOnterminate, control thread termination yourself and you'll never get these kind of problems again...

Comment: I just reproduced the same problem in a NEW XE2 service which has nothing even in it. All I do is add `while not Terminated do begin .. end;` in the `OnExecute` event handler. See added code above.

Comment: add  ProcessRequests(False); in your loop and you'll be fine

Comment: @whosrdaddy That did it! (btw it's `ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);`) So is this something new since D7 or something which was there but didn't surface until now?

Comment: @JerryDodge I don't know, I'm looking at D5 source code and it is roughly still the same. Updated my response BTW. My other point is still valid though

Comment: @whosrdaddy I had not seem your comment regarding `ProcessRequests` when I wrote my answer. I came to the same conclusion independently. However, I have deleted my answer since you clearly preceeded me.

Comment: Whosrdaddy's expertise is valuable, as I've seen elsewhere, and he deserves to grow his reputation number here. Accepted.

Comment: @Jerry This was a good question and you responded well to requests for more info and a smaller example. Upvotes well deserved. Naturally you picked up one downvote but it seems all Delphi questions do.

Comment: In the end, it wasn't that I was doing "something wrong" but rather wasn't doing "something right".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look at the source code for the Execute method:

```
procedure TServiceThread.Execute;
var
  msg: TMsg;
  Started: Boolean;
begin
  PeekMessage(msg, 0, WM_USER, WM_USER, PM_NOREMOVE); { Create message queue }
  try
    // Allow initialization of the Application object after
    // StartServiceCtrlDispatcher to prevent conflicts under
    // Windows 2003 Server when registering a class object with OLE.
    if Application.DelayInitialize then
      Application.Initialize;
    FService.Status := csStartPending;
    Started := True;
    if Assigned(FService.OnStart) then FService.OnStart(FService, Started);
    if not Started then Exit;
    try
      FService.Status := csRunning;
      if Assigned(FService.OnExecute) then
        FService.OnExecute(FService)
      else
        ProcessRequests(True);
      ProcessRequests(False);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        FService.LogMessage(Format(SServiceFailed,[SExecute, E.Message]));
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      FService.LogMessage(Format(SServiceFailed,[SStart, E.Message]));
  end;
end;
```

as you can see if you don't assign a OnExecute method, Delphi will process SCM requests (Service Start, Stop, ...) until the service is stopped.
When you make an loop in the Service.Execute you must to process SCM requests yourself by calling `ProcessRequests(False)`. A good habit is not to use Service.execute and start your workerthread in the Service.OnStart event and terminating/freeing it in the Service.OnStop event.

As told in the comments, another problem lies in the `FUpdateThread.Terminate` part.
David Heffernan was spot on with the Free/WaitFor comment.
Make sure you end your thread in correct fashion using synchronisation objects.

Comment: +1 I recommend that you swap around the two points in this answer. The ProcessRequests is the key and it should come first.