# Initialising Variables of a given class in Delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm really sorry to have to ask this, but I clearly don't understand something fundamental to Delphi.

When you declare a variable of a class like TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL, what do you have to initiate it to? Clearly if it was a string or an integer then the requisite value would be a string on an integer, but in this case it is less obvious(to people as incapable as me). Not initiating it results in an access violation, and I understand why having found an article on it [here at about.com](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-w1036.htm), but that article doesn't explain what to initiate to.

Below is the code that gives the access violation because I haven't initiated the variable client (it's an application without a gui)

```
program New;

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes,
  Sockets, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent,
  IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdIOHandler, IdIOHandlerSocket, IdIOHandlerStack,
  IdServerIOHandler, IdSSL, IdSSLOpenSSL;


function Handshake(target: string; port: integer) : string;
var client: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
client.Create();
client.Port := port;
client.Destination := target;
client.Destroy;
end;


begin

  Handshake('127.0.0.1',15);

end.
```

Apologies for my ignorance,

N

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the syntax `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create` to invoke a constructor and save the result to the instance variable:

```
function Handshake(target: string; port: integer) : string;
var
  client: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  client := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  try
    client.Port := port;
    client.Destination := target;
    Result := ...;//don't forget to assign the return value to something
  finally
    client.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Also use `try/finally` to protect the lifetime of the object in the face of exceptions. The `finally` block will always execute, providing that execution passes try.

And to destroy an object you should call `Free` rather than `Destroy`. This doesn't matter here, but is very important when you destroy objects inside another object's destructor. To learn more on the topic of `Free` I refer you (immodest I know) to [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things/8550628#8550628).

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That was way faster than I expected too!