# Assigned(my_var) evaluates to True where var evaluates to Nil (!!??)

Tags: delphi, null

It may not be relevant, but I recently re-installed Delphi XE2.

I have a variable `path` (of type TPath, a TMS Gogole maps thing, although I doubt that that is important).

I halt in the debugger and evaluate `path`, which evaluates as `Nil`.

If I run, I am getting an exception, `Read of address 0`, which I suspect to be because of this.

When I then evaluate `Assigned(path)` at the same time that `path = Nil` it evolutes to `True` (same result when I stop on the `ShowMessage` line - which is executed)).

Can someone explain that to me?

Clean & rebuild changes nothing. Might it be better to remove & reinstall Delphi?

(apologies to @mbratch , I used `var` for demo, the real name is actully `path`)

---

[Update] Full code sample as provided by TMS and working for them (in a different tiem zone, which is why I ask here too).

`This was retested here with:`

```
 uses
   uwebgmapspolylines;

 procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 var
   p: TPath;
 begin
   p := TPath.Create;

   if Assigned(p) then
     ShowMessage('creation OK');
 end;
```

`and this proves the correct creation of TPath returns a valid instance.`

When I stop at `if Assigned(p) then` and evaluate `p` I get `Nil`, but when I evaluate `Assigned(p)` I get `True`.

When I hover the cursor over the variable declaration in the IDE, shows that the type is declared in UWebGMapsPolyLines

---

[Futher update] Two votes to close? Seriously? I guess from folks who think that this just can't be - and yet it is!!!

The strange thing is that @j tried it and got `p <> Nil`. However, I tried it on a second PC and still get `p = Nil` using the code posted here, which was provided by TMS.

I admit that it seems strange, but I can reproduce it on 2 PCs. P is Nil and yet it is Assigned().

I don't have the code of Assigend() to step into. Also, I changed the code slightly to explicitly `if System.Assigned(p)` and still got the same result. Any suggestions?

[image: Assigned, or not?]

Comment: The variable is actually called `var`? Isn't `var` a Delphi (Pascal) keyword?

Comment: So you have any `with` statements that may be confusing the debugger?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show your actual code? With that we should be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: What does `p` look like if you stop the debugger on the `ShowMessage` (which I assume is executed if `Assigned(p)` is `true`)?

Comment: Are you sure the compiler isn't removing the "impossible" condition - as the only way for p to equal nil would be if an exception occurs in its constructor, in which case the code wouldn't reach the `if Assigned...`.

Comment: Very hard to believe this is the case. Assigned implementation is known to be correct.

Comment: @Gerry The compiler never does optimisations like that

Comment: Try to trace into the `Assigned` method. I presume it is a different one from `System.Assigned` (use the Delphi built-in CPU debugger if you don't have the source for this particular `Assigned` method).

Comment: Do you have the source of the component? Perhaps the constructor calls `Free()` if something goes wrong during the initialization.

Comment: @iManBiglari Perhaps? When a constructor raises an exception, the framework calls `Destroy` on the partially constructed object. But if that happens, the code never reaches `if Assigned`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What if the constructor doesn't raise an exception, and instead calls `Free()` itself? I know this is a very bad practice, but it's a possibility.

Comment: @iManBiglari That would be insane, but it would not influence `Assigned`. It's a common mistake to think that when an object is freed that `Assigned()` returns `False`. I offer an answer of mine as a guide to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things/8550628#8550628

Comment: RE, your picture: The items in the parenthesis in the local variables panel are *fields* of the corresponding object. Your *p* there has only one field and that's nil. For an unassigned *p*, the debugger will refuse to resolve the fields with the note *inaccessible value*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used exactly your code (with Delphi XE2) and found this :

[image: TPath breakpoint]

[image: TPath watch]

Are you perhaps confusing `FOwner = nil` for `p = nil`?  `TPath` inherits from `TPersistent` so you can pass it an owner (although it is optional to do so).  You could, for example, do :

```
 p := TPath.Create(self);
```

**EDIT**

Try this :

```
   var p:TPath
   begin
*1   if assigned(p) then ShowMessage('foo');
     p:=nil;
     if assigned(p) then ShowMessage('bar');
     p:=TPath.Create;
     if assigned (p) then ShowMessage('ok');
   end;
```

Put your breakpoint on `*1`- you should see in a watch or local variable window :

```
 p       *Inaccessible Value*
```

Local variables for non reference-counted reference types are not initialized to zero/nil - they contain whatever random data happened to be in the space allocated to them.  *'Inaccessible Value'* means that whatever that random data is, it does not point to a readable memory address in your program's memory space.

Step to the next line -- >  'foo' --> `if assigned(p)...`

You see the message...why?!  `Assigned` only checks for `nil` - since the local variable is not initialized, Assigned returns true (it does not know that you have given it an uninitialized local variable - it only knows you gave it something not `nil`).  This is also why it is a bad idea to free an uninitialized local variable.

Step to the next line -- >  p := nil --> `if assigned(p)...`

When you step past p:=nil you should see that *Inaccessible Value* changes to :

```
 p       nil
```

And you will not see the message 'bar' (remember, assigned(p) only checks for `nil`).  Note that `nil` is naked in the watch - no parentheses!  Stepping through to the end you see `p`'s value change again in the watch after it has been created :

```
 p       (nil)
```

Like Sertac explained in comments, when an object has been created the watch/locals windows show you their member contents in parentheses.   The above shows us that `p` is not `nil` (*without* parentheses), it is not uninitialized (ie:not *inaccessible value*), and that it also contains a member field (expanding shows it is `FOwner`) that has been initialized to nil and has not been assigned a value.

The short lesson is that `Assigned` is only really useful for Fields or globals and not for non-reference-counted local variables - the former are initialized to `nil` when an object is created, the latter are not (when you enter a method).

Comment: +1 You may well be onto something here. When I use your suggestion, `p := TPath.Create(self);` p does have a non-Nil value. I will request clarification, since they sent me the code sample with no parameter. Thanks, I imagine that I will award you the answer after they reply.

Comment: @Mawg - But what are you seeing when you say "It evaluates to nil"?  Do you see all of those items as I've posted above?  A `TPath` is an object with many items in it(here we see an FItemPath, FItems, FUpdateCount, FNext, etc). Here the TPath is created just fine (ie: is not nil) - only that its FOwner field is `nil`.  `p` itself can be non-nil and still have fields within it that are `nil` - clearly this is what `IfAssigned(p)` is telling you when it returns true. There is no need to assign FOwner for `p` if you don't need it (FOwner = nil is OK)-it also doesn't mean that `p` itself is `nil`.

Comment: @Mawg  I'll add that I have no idea why your watch only shows (nil) and mine shows more objects - maybe we have different versions of the TMS component (I just downloaded the demo from their site).  I'm not aware of any options in delphi to change the behaviour of what is and is not reported in the locals window (maybe you don't have all the XE2 updates?  Starter version?)