# Checking form's existence doesn't work

Tags: forms, delphi, constructor

I have a Form for which I coded my own constructor:

```
constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; AParent: TWinControl; ASender: TMyClass;
   ATab: String); reintroduce; overload;
```

To create such a form I use the following:

```
try
  MyForm := TMyClassForm.Create(nil, Self.Parent, Self as TMyClass, 'FirstTab');
  MyForm.ShowModal;
finally
  MyForm.Free;
end;
```

Somewhere else, before starting a procedure, I need to check whether this form is opened or not, so I check its existence with:

```
if (Assigned(MyForm)) and (MyForm.Active) and (MyForm.Showing) then
  // Don't do the procedure
else
  // Do the procedure
```

Now, if I open the form and close it, and I check this conditional statement, everytime I get true,  but the Form is not opened and not showing anymore, because I freed it after creating.

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You called `Free` on the `MyForm` global method, but you did not modify the reference. So, `MyForm` still refers to the now destroyed form. And so `Assigned(MyForm)` evaluates as `True`, and then the other two tests operate on the stale object reference. Anything could happen when you operate on a stale object reference. In the situations that you have tried, it seems that the operations both return `True`. But another time you might get an access violation.

You'll want to set the `MyForm` variable to `nil` after call `Free`. At the risk of re-starting the great religious Delphi war of our times, you might contemplate using `FreeAndNil(MyForm)` in place of `MyForm.Free`.

You might find my answer here to be instructive: [Why should I not use "if Assigned()" before using or freeing things?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things/8550628#8550628)

Comment: It worked perfect, but I expected that Free would make this task of setting the variable to nil... don't see the point of don't doing that. Thanks a lot

Comment: Ironic that my linking of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things/8550628#8550628 led to somebody removing an upvote from that answer.

Comment: @Felipe: calling Free() does not automatically nil the variable, you have to use FreeAndNil() for that (actually, Free() does nil the variable in the iOS compiler under ARC, but that is an exception to the rule right now).

Comment: @Felipe The answer that I linked to in the final paragraph covers in much detail the exact topic you raise in your comment

Answer (score 1):

1. Init:
   MyForm := nil;
2. User FreeAndNil(MyForm)
3. if (Assigned(MyForm)) then
   DON'T DO THE PROCEDURE
   else
   DO THE PROCEDURE