# How to properly start, working and finish a transaction?

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

I'm using MySQL, and I know that Nested Connection are not allowed - use "save points" for this - but I would like create a more generic code that could also be used with other DBMS.

So, I would like know how to properly start, working and finish a transaction in the code below?

Once `ExampleDAO.Save()` function could be used inside other function, like `OtherExampleDAO.Save()`, I need verify a transaction has been started before I try start a new one.

The lines with the verification `if Assigned(dbTransaction) then` always returns true, so how to properly verify if `dbTransaction` was instantiated?

```
function TExampleDAO.Save(const Example: TExample): Boolean;
var
  dbxTransaction: TDBXTransaction;
begin
  if Assigned(Example) then // prevents invalid object, like ExampleDAO.Save(nil);
  begin
    try
      if (_connection.TransactionsSupported) AND
        ((not _connection.InTransaction) OR (_connection.MultipleTransactionsSupported)) then
      begin
        dbxTransaction := _connection.BeginTransaction(TDBXIsolations.ReadCommitted);
      end;

      try
        // example
        _sqlQuery.Close;
        _sqlQuery.SQL.Clear;
        _sqlQuery.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO example(a, b) '
                        + 'VALUES(:a, :b)');
        _sqlQuery.ParamByName('a').AsAnsiString := Example.A;
        _sqlQuery.ParamByName('b').AsDateTime := Example.B;
        _sqlQuery.ExecSQL(False);

        // example info
        _sqlQuery.Close;
        _sqlQuery.SQL.Clear;
        _sqlQuery.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO example_info(c, d) '
                        + 'VALUES(:c, :d)');
        _sqlQuery.ParamByName('c').AsInteger := Example.Info.C;
        _sqlQuery.ParamByName('d').AsFloat := Example.Info.D;
        _sqlQuery.ExecSQL(False);

        if Assigned(dbxTransaction) then
          _connection.CommitFreeAndNil(dbxTransaction);

        Result := True;
      except
        on Exc:Exception do
        begin
          if Assigned(dbxTransaction) then
            _connection.RollBackFreeAndNil(dbxTransaction);

          raise Exc;
          Result := False;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      if Assigned(dbxTransaction) then
        FreeAndNil(dbxTransaction);
    end;    
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `Result := False;` after the `raise` is useless. I would raise an `EArgumentNilException` if `Example` is not assigned and turn it from a function into a procedure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things

Comment: Assigning to Result is useless before the raise too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly initialize `dbxTransaction` to `nil` at the start of your function. Local variables in Delphi (on the Win32 platform, at least) are not initialized until a value is assigned to them, meaning that the content is unknown. Passing any value other than `nil` to `Assigned` will result in `True`. I recommend never testing a local variable's content on *any* platform until it has had a value assigned in your code.

Here's an example of how to make it work. (I've also removed the unnecessary assignment to `Result` in the exception block.)

```
function TExampleDAO.Salve(const Example: TExample): Boolean;
var
  dbxTransaction: TDBXTransaction;
begin
  dbxTransaction := nil;            // Initialize the transaction variable here

  if Assigned(Example) then // prevents invalid object, like ExampleDAO.Save(nil);
  begin
    try
      if (_connection.TransactionsSupported) AND
        ((not _connection.InTransaction) OR (_connection.MultipleTransactionsSupported)) then
      begin
        dbxTransaction := _connection.BeginTransaction(TDBXIsolations.ReadCommitted);
      end;

      try
        // example
        _sqlQuery.Close;
        _sqlQuery.SQL.Clear;
        _sqlQuery.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO example(a, b) '
                        + 'VALUES(:a, :b)');
        _sqlQuery.ParamByName('a').AsAnsiString := Example.A;
        _sqlQuery.ParamByName('b').AsDateTime := Example.B;
        _sqlQuery.ExecSQL(False);

        // example info
        _sqlQuery.Close;
        _sqlQuery.SQL.Clear;
        _sqlQuery.SQL.Add('INSERT INTO example_info(c, d) '
                        + 'VALUES(:c, :d)');
        _sqlQuery.ParamByName('c').AsInteger := Example.Info.C;
        _sqlQuery.ParamByName('d').AsFloat := Example.Info.D;
        _sqlQuery.ExecSQL(False);

        if Assigned(dbxTransaction) then
          _connection.CommitFreeAndNil(dbxTransaction);

        Result := True;
      except
        on Exc:Exception do
        begin
          if Assigned(dbxTransaction) then
            _connection.RollBackFreeAndNil(dbxTransaction);

          raise Exc;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      if Assigned(dbxTransaction) then
        FreeAndNil(dbxTransaction);
    end;    
  end
  else
  begin
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

As was noted by @SirRufo in the comments to your question, failing to pass `Example` as a parameter should probably raise an exception as well, which would mean that it could become a procedure instead of a function and `Result` would no longer apply at all.

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite. 
At the moment, I can not change the function, to be a procedure, because others objects are expecting the True result of the function to continue their execution. So, I'm also starting the Result := False, at the begin of the function.
You can check the final code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c1ce27723cf793828c66