# Access violation when freeing TBitmap variable -- Bitmap variable still assigned after freeing?

Tags: delphi, free, delphi-10.1-berlin, tbitmap

I have this code in a VCL Forms Application:

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  MyBitmap: TBitmap;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyBitmap := TBitmap.Create;
end;

procedure TFormMain.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(MyBitmap) then
    MyBitmap.Free;
end;

procedure TFormMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(MyBitmap) then
    MyBitmap.Free;
end;
```

When I click the button the second time I get an Access violation in `MyBitmap.Free;` in the button's click handler. But `MyBitmap` shouldn't be anymore assigned after the first button click. So why the condition `if Assigned(MyBitmap) then` does not work on the second button click when it obviously did work on the first button click?

Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2

Comment: Assigned checks for being equal to  nil, freeing an object reference does not make it nil. Hence you are attempting a double free.

Comment: It seems that `System.SysUtils.FreeAndNil(MyBitmap)` does the job without AV.

Comment: So, conclusively we have learned: An OBJECT can be RELEASED with `FREE` and an OBJECT VARIABLE can be SET to `NIL`, not vice-versa. Is this correct?

Comment: What exactly happens when `MyObject.Free` is executed? Is the memory for the object explicitly released? How exactly is it released? What does this mean in practice?

Comment: Practically you could say that freeing is responsible for releasing resources that is acquired for the object, including memory.

Comment: What does "releasing" exactly mean? Does it tell Windows that the memory space previously occupied by `MyObject` is not needed anymore and can now be used for other purposes?

Comment: Yep. Practically though, the probability is higher that the memory manager reserves unused space, for later use, instead of giving it back to the OS.

Comment: Is the "memory manager" a feature of the program or a feature of Windows?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Memory_Management

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548843/why-should-i-not-use-if-assigned-before-using-or-freeing-things

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Assigned` function only checks the pointer to be `Nil`. It doesn't perform a check whether the it's pointing to an existing object or not. You need to set it to `Nil` after freeing it in order to get the `Assigned` function work as you expect it. `FreeAndNil` performs both instructions.

Comment: Is there a common rule for when to use `Free` and when to use `FreeAndNil` when releasing an object variable?

Comment: @user - If there is a probability that an object can be freed from multiple places, FreeAndNil can be useful. But that's not very common.

Comment: This is opinion based. IMHO you should set the object reference to `Nil` after freeing it when the variable can be accessed after the referenced object has been freed. So you don't need to `Nil` local variables in a method when there is nothing about to happen after the `Free`. Nobody can access these variables afterwards. The same applies for object references stored in member variables of a class and which are freed in its destructor. But you should `Nil` them additionaly when you `Free` them during the lifetime of that object (e.g. freeing a form's member inside a button click).