# How to compleate release Child Form from Memory allocation

Tags: delphi

I have sample code below
can someone explain why delphi compiler not release all memory allocation
for object so nil checking is always true. im using release method for destroying TLoginForm im not using free method because that gave me exception when some interfaced event called before free or after it.

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  {some stuf}
  public
    procedure Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    procedure doLogout();
  end;

  TChildBase = class(TForm)
  {some stuf}
  public
    procedure Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TLoginForm = class(TChildBase)
  public
    procedure doLogin();
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm; {<== created automaticaly at runtime}
  LoginForm: TLoginForm; {<== created at create event in TMainForm}

implementation

{TLoginForm}
procedure TLoginForm.doLogin;
begin
  if true then
  begin
    { Do Interfaced Event to main form }
    Release;
  end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin 
  inherited;
  FormStyle := fsMDIForm;
  LoginForm := TLoginForm.Create(Application); {Create login form}
end;

procedure TMainForm.doLogout;
begin
  { Do Interfaced Event to Child Form except TLoginForm to close}

  if LoginForm <> nil then    {<== this still alocated at memory}
    LoginForm := TLoginForm.Create(Application)
  else
    LoginForm.Show; {<== Error raised here.}
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowhere in your code do you set the variable `LoginForm` to `nil`. So it retains its value even after the object it refers to has been destroyed. If you wish this variable to be set to `nil` you must explicitly do that.

You should find this answer to a related question helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550628/

In essence, the issue behind your question can perhaps better be understood with this simple example:

```
obj := TObject.Create;
obj.Free;
Assert(Assigned(obj));
```

Destroying an object does not clear the variables that refer to it.

Yes, in your code you use `Release` rather than `Free` but the fundamental concept is exactly the same.

Comment: Mr. David, you right, i check the reason when i put checking at doLogout for resonable reason. so my method for checking was wrong when compare it to nil. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550628/ was helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

`Release()` is just a delayed destruction. It posts a `CM_RELEASE` message to the Form, and then the Form calls `Free` on itself when it processes that message.

Freeing a Form object (or  any other object, for that matter) does not automatically set any pointers to that object to nil.  You have to do that manually in your own code.  In this case, you can set the global `LoginForm` pointer to nil in `TLoginForm`'s destructor or `OnDestroy` event.

You might also consider using the `TLoginForm.OnClose` event instead of calling `Release()` directly.  Have `doLogin()` call `Close()`, and when the Form is actually closed, set the event's `Action` parameter to `caFree` so the Form frees itself (via `Release()`).  You still have to set the global `LoginForm` pointer to `nil` manually, though.