# Class or record (<T>)

Tags: delphi

How can I determine whether a Delphi < T > is of a specific class and not for example record?
I want to release an element of a list, if it is a class when cleaning.

```
procedure TTableData<T>.Delete(Index: Integer);
begin
  if Items[Index] is TClass then TClass(Items[Index]).Free;
  inherited Delete(Index);
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RTTI, perhaps like this:

```
uses
  System.TypInfo;

....

procedure TTableData<T>.Delete(Index: Integer);
var
  item: T;
begin
  if PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T)).Kind = tkClass then
  begin
    item := Items[index];
    TObject((@item)^).Free;
  end;
  inherited Delete(Index);
end;
```

Comment: `if Assigned(TObject((@Item)^)) then TObject((@Item)^).Free;`
raise Exception if `Item` is already destroyed. And this check does not help. How to check?

Comment: `First chance exception at $74FBC54F. Exception class EInvalidPointer with message 'Invalid pointer operation'. Process Yotm.exe (7144)`
`procedure TObject.FreeInstance;
    begin
    CleanupInstance;
    --> _FreeMem(Pointer(Self));
    end;`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8550628/505088 You cannot check whether or not an object has already been destroyed. You need to decide on the ownership policy for this container and follow it strictly. You can't mix and match ownership.

Comment: FYI, `PTypeInfo(TypeInfo(T)).Kind` can be replaced with `GetTypeKind(T)` in Delphi XE7+